# Handle an express redirect from Angular POST

Tags: javascript, redirect, angularjs, express

I'm using Expressjs as an API and I'm using angular to hit that POST. I would like to respond to the redirect that express is sending. Success from my Angular POST returns a HTML of the page I intend to redirect to but nothing happens on my DOM. I can see that my redirect is working in my network traffic, and that console.log data, below contains the DOM of the redirected page.

How can I refresh the DOM, to reflect this successful POST, or handle the "redirect"?

ANGULAR CODE:

```
   $http({method: 'POST', url: '/login', data:FormData}).
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log(data)
    }).
      error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    });

    $scope.userName = '';
```

Expressjs API:

```
    app.post('/login', function(req, res){

        var name = req.param('name', null);  // second parameter is default
    var password = req.param('password', "changeme")

    // Lots Authenticationcode
    // returns succesfful login
    res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/'); 

  }); // end app.post
```

console.log(data)  (from Angular POST success)

```
returns the HTML of the page I intended to redirect to
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

AngularJS is meant to work as a client-side framework coupled with (mostly) RESTfull APIs. Your login API isn't supposed to return a HTML, it is supposed to return the *instruction to redirect*. So in your case you should simply call `$location.url('/')` in your `$http` success callback, which would use the Angular router to "redirect" to '/' (the root URL).

Comment: How does one detect the 'instruction to redirect' in Angular?  In the op's example using Express, does Angular expose some way of detecting  res.redirect('/') coming from the server?

Comment: It's up to the developer, but in most cases you want to return status code 200 (success) or 201 (created), in which case you simply put the `$location.url('/')` call in `$http` success callback.

Comment: how can i mimic the traditional <form action='/auth/signin' method='POST'> way of posting data where res.redirect works?