# How to follow a redirect in http.get in AngularJS?

Tags: redirect, angularjs, http-get

I am working on a website for coaches to help people have healthier lives by using social media. On the moment I am working on access to Twitter through OAuth in a ExpressJS server with AngularJS in the frontend.

From the [website of AngularJS](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http):

> A response status code between 200 and 299 is considered a success status and will result in the success callback being called. Note that if the response is a redirect, XMLHttpRequest will transparently follow it, meaning that the error callback will not be called for such responses.

The full code of my server can be found in [web.js](https://github.com/mrquincle/sensorcoach/blob/master/web.js) and [twitter.js](https://github.com/mrquincle/sensorcoach/blob/master/assets/js/twitter.js) on github, but this is the caller:

```js
function LoginCtrl($scope, $http, $location) {
  $scope.welcome = 'Sign in with Twitter';
  $http.defaults.useXDomain = true;    
  $scope.submit = function() {    
    $http({method: 'GET', url: '/sessions/connect'}).
    success(function(data, status) {
        $scope.welcome = data;
    });
  };
}
```

And this is the callee in web.js:

```js
app.get('/sessions/connect', function(req, res){
  consumer().getOAuthRequestToken(function(error, oauthToken, oauthTokenSecret, results){
    if (error) {
      res.send("Error getting OAuth request token : " + sys.inspect(error), 500);
    } else {  
      req.session.oauthRequestToken = oauthToken;
      req.session.oauthRequestTokenSecret = oauthTokenSecret;
      res.redirect("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token="+req.session.oauthRequestToken);      
    }
  });
});
```

If I check with `tcpdump` (sorry I'm old-fashioned) I see:

```js
Connection:.keep-alive....Moved.Temporarily..Redirecting.to.https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=***
```

This is really nice of course, and indeed happens when I go to this server `/sessions/connect` manually in the browser. However, with AngularJS my browser screen is not actually redirected. Why not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$http` goes and gets the contents of the page for you. However, it gives you the results back in the promise. It doesn't change your page at all unless you ask it to. In your `then` handler, you can do something to redirect your page. There's an example of how you can do that here: [Handle an express redirect from Angular POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629057/handle-an-express-redirect-from-angular-post)

Comment: But if I use `res.send("redirection suggestion to https://")` I will redirect myself to the twitter page. From there something on my server will be called (the route `/sessions/callback`), and I will not be able to obtain the response object to that callback in the AngularJS controller isn't it? Is using `oauth` on the server together with AngularJS perhaps not possible?

Comment: @ondervloei Twitter spells out the OAuth process on their website: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/implementing-sign-twitter You're to redirect the browser to Twitter, and Twitter will redirect back to your server with the token. You can then pass the token back to Angular from your server. If you want to keep your page there, you can open a new window.

Comment: I've implemented oauth before in C++. Sorry, I'm not so experienced in the interactions between server-side and client-side code as required here. I think I've figured out the general scheme though, namely by setting up routes on the client side with AngularJS. There are quite some pieces to this puzzle and referring me to these websites presumes I didn't visit them. :-)

Comment: @ondervloei I see. You need the browser to be redirected to Twitter for OAuth to work. Otherwise, Twitter cannot be sure that their user's credentials are protected. You could maybe use an iframe. The whole point is to give Twitter absolute control so that they can authorize the user.

Comment: sorry but this doesn't work. Angular fetches the redirected page before you can issue a redirect to the user-agent.