# Spring Security CAS grails plugin with AngularJS, login page does not show up

Tags: javascript, angularjs, grails

I am using grails springsecurity CAS in the server side and frontend is AngularJS.

Both the projects(grails + AngularJS) are running in the same server but different port.

In AngularJS I am loading some database values from a grails controller through a REST service, which works fine without springsecurity CAS plugin integration.

But the same thing does not work when I integrate springsecurity CAS plugin in server side. Login page does not show up and data also does not come from server as it is not authenticated, console shows access is denied.

When I hit the server url in a browser it asks for the authentication. After successful login if I run the index.html in the same browser session data comes fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login page does not show up because Angular's $http service does not handle 302, see 
[How to follow a redirect in http.get in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496452/how-to-follow-a-redirect-in-http-get-in-angularjs)