# Using $http.post and res.redirect without resolving the promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express, response.redirect

I am using an $http.post call to my server and sending over some user data:

```
$http.post('/streamdb/create/',{user:$scope.user.username})
```

My server then performs a series of operations and retrieves a certain id from the DB. 
I would like to have the client redirected to the page ('streams/'+id), so I have the operations terminate with a

```
res.redirect('/streams/'+id)
```

I could send over the id:

```
res.json({id:id})
```

and then respond to a .success() clause with a $location, or window.open (as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11907961/redirect-using-angularjs), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629057/handle-an-express-redirect-from-angular-post)) but that seems a little wasteful: the server already knows where to send me, why should I make an additional call?

While the server shows that the routing was done, the new page never renders, it just stays on the original page.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your server side code cannot redirect the browser from an ajax response. The only reason that redirecting from the server side works without ajax is you are actually sending a fresh page each time, so a redirect means simply serving a different page. Ajax requests dont get served an entire new page as a response, so you are stuck on the current one. You need to go the 'wasteful' route :) Return the id in the response body and redirect using the angular $location service like you mentioned. I recommend using a promise and performing the redirect once it resolves.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629057/handle-an-express-redirect-from-angular-post