# Redirect issue from localhost using Play Framework & Angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, scala, playframework

I am using Play Framework and Angularjs for my application. My requirement is to redirect Play framework page based on some parameter selected on UI.

Here is my code,

On Page I opened bootstrap modal dialog and on submit action calling angular post method,

```
$scope.loginToExt = function() {

  var data = $scope.env;

  $http.post('/login', {env: data})
    .success(function(data){
      //$scope.env = data
    })
    .error(function(data){
      console.log(data)
    });
};
```

Once I click submit on my modal it will call '/login' and based on my route mapping will call action method as below,

```
def login = Action(parse.json) { implicit request =>
val env = (request.body \ "env").as[String]

env match {
  case _ => {
    Redirect("https://google.com")
      .withHeaders(ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN -> "*")
  }
}
```

Route file as below,

```
POST     /login             controllers.Application.login
```

I don't know what the issue is but I was getting error as below and unable to redirect my page.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://google.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue you are having is because you are trying to redirect inside an ajax ($http.post) call, see this post:

> Your server side code cannot redirect the browser from an ajax
>   response.

[Using $http.post and res.redirect without resolving the promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577745/using-http-post-and-res-redirect-without-resolving-the-promise?lq=1)

See also:
[Handle an express redirect from Angular POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629057/handle-an-express-redirect-from-angular-post)

Instead of trying to redirect from Play, consider returning a response with the url of the redirect, then in your success call back, redirect from there:

```
$window.location.href = "https://google.com";
```

(remember to inject $window)

Comment: Thanks for your help...but is there any way I can redirect it from Play Controller ?

Comment: I don't think so.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15996968/1956540,  in the comments it is pointed out that because of the nature of XHR requests, redirects in this fashion are not going to work.

Comment: Thanks again for you time. It seems difficult to achieve this using javascript so I have replace javascript logic with play html form and controller based native logic. No JavaScript used now and now it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

By looking 
https://gist.github.com/mitchwongho/78cf2ae0276847c9d332 , 
You have to add **"access-control-allow-origin"** in **HeaderNames.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS** in **Global.scala** file.