# REST calls for login process, how do we handle redirects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I have created a new REST call, which accepts the `username` and `password` and does verify the username and password.

On top of this REST call, I'm building the UI with angular js. REST call will send JSON as when its success:

```
{ success : { username : 'batman' } }
```

Now I want angular js to redirect to the home page. How should I do that?

Is REST calls for login is a good design choice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629057/handle-an-express-redirect-from-angular-post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're making a request through ajax to login, I believe your api might need to return a reponse that lets your front end app know to redirect, and then redirect in javascript.

Using angular on success you should be able to change location using [`$location`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

Comment: So the rest call should send redirect url?

Comment: If your API endpoint redirects  how will that be interpreted in your ajax call from the front end? If you send a redirect, the response to your front end wont actually change the page.

Comment: Can you give an example of `$location`?

Answer (score -1):

you have to send the redirect from the Server....
If you are using NODEjs and passport then theres a built in redirect function :)