# How to redirect url from angularjs login submission via laravel 5

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

i'm developing my website with angularjs and laravel5. i wrote code for login and registration page in both angularjs and laravel5 where validate my value and insert everything works good but redirect url in laravel 5 not occur .
i wrote code like `return redirect('Home/profile')` in login controller. it returns total page to angularjs controller not redirecting page.

`routes.php` in laravel:

```
Route::group(array('prefix'=>'api'),function(){
    Route::resource('register','Registration\RegisterController@basicForm');
    Route::resource('login','Registration\RegisterController@makeLogin');
});
```

my controller :

```
public function makeLogin()
{
    $email=Input::get('email');
    $pwd=Input::get('pwd');
    $verify=Authenticated::attempt($email,$pwd);
    if($verify)
    {
        return redirect('Home/profile');
    }
    else if($verify=='user')
    {
        return redirect('/')->with('Email address mismatch');
    }
    else if($verify=='pwd')
    {
        return redirect('/')->with('Password Authentication Failed');
    }
}
```

i send post request from angular js controller via factory method:

```
this.scope.authUserInfo.authenticateUser(this.scope.signin).then(function(data){
    console.log(data.data);
});
```

In this console.log,display 'Home/profile' page

Comment: We can't guess at your login process flow or your code. The process is totally unclear and you provided no code. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
    return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
}`

Comment: i tried this method also.it return total html page to my angular js controller not redirected page

Answer (score 0):

I can see many mistakes in the Laravel code.

What is `Authenticated` in your code? The authentication service in Laravel is called `Auth`. The way you use the `attempt()` method is not correct; this is the method signature:

```
attempt(array $credentials = array(), bool $remember = false, bool $login = true)
```

so you should pass the email and the password in the first parameter as an array, something like:

```
$verify = Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' =>
```

Moreover, the `attempt()` method returns a boolean: `true` on success and `false` on failure. Your code

```
if ($verify) {
    // ...
} else if ($verify == 'user') {
    // ...
} else if ($verify == 'pwd') {
    // ...
}
```

has no sense and you never run the `else` parts because on failure `false` is always different from either `'user'` or `'pwd'`. So, when the authentication fails you reach the end of the `makeLogin()` method and Laravel returns a blank page.

You should use something like:

```
if ($verify) {
    // authenticated: go to the profile page
} else {
    // username OR password are wrong
}
```

(In my opinion you shouldn't give hints on what of the two is wrong for security reasons: a potential attacker would know if he/she guessed a right email and concentrate the attempts on guessing the password.)

If you really want to give a hint to the user on what was wrong with her data, you should use a different technique, like searching the `users` table for a record with the right email to know whether the user exists (the provided password was wrong) or not (the provided email was wrong).

On the client side, I don't think Angular will redirect on your own. See answer to [Handle an express redirect from Angular POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16629057/handle-an-express-redirect-from-angular-post), even if in that question the server uses ExpressJs and not Laravel, but the basics are the same.

You should understand that in most cases an Angular client expect to receive only data and not a full HTML page. Here is my little attempt to do what you want:

On the Laravel side:

```
public function makeLogin(Request $request)
{
    $email = $request->get('email');
    $pwd = $request->get('pwd');

    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $pwd])) {
        // authenticated!

        // if you return an array from a controller public method, Laravel
        // will convert it to JSON; I also use the url() Laravel helper to
        // generate a fully qualified url to the path
        return [
            'status' => 'redirect',
            'to' => url('home/profile')
        ];
    }

    // failed
    return [
        'status' => 'failed',
        'message' => 'Email or password are wrong'
    ];
}
```

Now the method will return a JSON answer. On the Angular side, you can do something like (I'm not an Angular guru, there could be mistakes here):

```
this.scope.authUserInfo.authenticateUser(this.scope.signin).then(function(data) {
    if (data.response == 'redirect') {
        $location.url(data.to);
    } else {
        // failed: you can show the error message
        console.log(data.message);
    }
});
```

---

**UPDATE**

I noticed there is something wrong in the routes too. Your controller *does not seems* a resourceful controller, so don't use the `Route::resource()` method. Use the `get()` and `post()` methods instead:

```
Route::group(array('prefix'=>'api'),function(){
    Route::get('register', 'Registration\RegisterController@basicForm');
    Route::post('login', 'Registration\RegisterController@makeLogin');
});
```

so that you can give the method that should be called in your controller.

Comment: thanks @marco pallante .i didn't use Auth helper functionality.i wrote customized Authenticated function

Comment: Ok, if you use a custom `Authenticated` class with your custom `attempt()` method, then you are not limited to a boolean result, but the idea behind my answer remains the same :)

Comment: how to use memcached in my project.i am creating social network like linked in . please refer some idea

Comment: That's another question unrelated to this one ;) (but I would suggest to take a deep look at the Laravel cache documentation.)

Comment: okay @marco.but i am beginner so i need clear about memcached and session handling process

Comment: If you have *specific* doubts about something, then ask here on StackOverflow. But if you just need general understanding of how things work in Laravel, then maybe you have to search for tutorials and guides elsewhere, like the Laravel docs pages or Laracasts, just to name a few starting points.